# Hardware encoding video on Android phone

Tags: android, video, encoding, hardware-acceleration

I'm looking for some information about encoding video on an Android phone using hardware acceleration. I know some phones (if anyone has a list?) support encoding for the camera, and was hoping I could access the chip to encode a live feed supplied through say wifi, usb.
Also, I'm interested in the latency any such chip would provide.

EDIT: Apparently Android uses PacketVideo, however not much documentation to be found for encoding.

EDIT: Android documentation shows a video-encoder: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html. However it does not say anything about hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 3):

[MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) should fit your needs. Documentation says nothing about hardware acceleration, but according to logs and benchmarks, it relies on OpenMAX library.

Comment: That's correct. Generic documentation does not specify hardware acceleration, because this is device-specific. But in reality, all devices I have ever used provide hw encoders and decoders for at least h263/mpeg2 and h264/avc (the supported profiles for latter may vary).

Comment: @AlexCohn I see `OMX.SEC.AVC.ENCODER.so` inside `/system/libs/`. Does it means the openmax il interface to the hardware chip or it's just an openmax il interface to a software implementation? I 'm sure about OMX.google.* are software OMX components, similarly i want to be sure about OMX.SEC.* !!

Comment: @nmxprime: Your persistence in looking for the answer is admirable, but asking the full question could save you time, and even be a better gift to community. Note that the situation with OpenMax is quickly changing, so the old questions and old answers may be irrelevant.

Regarding `OMX.SEC.AVC.ENCODER.so`, yes it is the connector between OpenMax IL and Samsung hardware h264 encoder. IIRC, you cannot use this component directly, unless you have root access (more precisely, if you can grant your app the `media` GID).

The best choice to connect to the media codec is through `libstagefright.so`.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thank you! So soon i'll bring up my own question because still i'm looking at android source to understand openmax